# What is a good strategy for printing the contents of two panels of a windows form?

Tags: c#, winforms, printing

I have written a C# 4.0 Windows Forms Application that creates two panels which are both populated exclusively with text labels. I would like to add functionality to my application to print these panels exactly as they appear on the form, but I only want to print these panels and their contents, with no background or other parts of the form.

[This link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6he9hz8c.aspx) was especially helpful as an overview, but so far I'm only able to print what amounts to a screen capture of the form. The entire form is included, buttons, trim, background, and all. It looks like I need to "rebuild" the form by creating a graphics object (I use the term generically, as I'm not sure what specific graphics-related class I need to employ) and somehow transfer the contents of the panel into this object.

My question is: what classes and/or methods should I research in order to build this graphical object? Also helpful to know: are there any handy tricks within the .NET framework or any libraries out there to automatically fit the result to a single page when building the PrintDocument object?

Comment: Would be useful to see both the screen grab of the form(s) and also how you'd like it to appear in print.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I found one way to do it (love to my Perl bros out there):

Wrap both panels in another parent Panel. Let's call this Panel "`parentPanel`." Create a bitmap (`memoryBitmap`)that is the size of `parentPanel` (`parentPanel.Size`).

Next: `parentPanel.DrawToBitmap(memoryBitmap, new Rectangle(parentPanel.Location, parentPanel.Size`)

Then, in the print page event handler: `e.Graphics.DrawImage(memoryBitmap, 0, 0)`

I'll leave this open in the likely event that someone else has a better idea.